# Unable to create gradle build with classes

Tags: java, build, gradle

my project structure is like that:

[image: shoot]

when I created gradle build with:

```
gradle clean build
```

with plugin

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

gradle created build, created jar file but not compile classes so folder build/classes/main is empty. Also there is no java.class in jar file. I thought that is problem with paths but resources folder is attached correctly. build.gradle file is very simple:

```
version = '1.0'
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I don't know what is the problem.
Generally I use intellij but build I tried do from console.

@Update:
Now I'm trying figure out what is wrong but when we solve that problem I would like to create war file and deploy to tomcat.

Comment: Adding "--info" or even "--debug" to the end of the command line might provide a clue.

Comment: Ok, I don't resolve the problem but I found different way. Generaly running task 'gradle build' runs also 'gradle compileJava' task but build/classes folder is empty. What I do is when I deploy to tomcat create three jobs: 1. gradle clean, 2. make (that is available from IntelliJ menu Build/Make project) - that task compile sources file correct, 3. 'gradle build' - create jar file with libs, resources and compiled classes